# how to set the system ip in the jvm argument?

Tags: java

I want to set the system ip for one of the jvm arguments when i launch my application. please need info on how to do that. I need to set the ip address of the machine from where the application is launched.

Comment: Which system IP are you talking about. Each interface on a machine has one or more IPs bound to it.

Comment: Please refine/define your question

Answer (score 4):

IP addresses are bound to network interfaces and are assigned by native operating system facilties; this assignment may involve using DHCP. You cannot bypass this process by passing a parameter to the JVM, that will automatically change the assigned IP address.

If you want to listen on a particular IP address, and if you are using `ServerSocket` to do so, use the [`ServerSocket.bind`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#bind%28java.net.SocketAddress%29) method to bind the process to a particular IP address. Again, this must be a valid IP address of one of the network interfaces owned by the system; you cannot simply listen on a different machine's endpoint.